# weka and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, data-mining, weka

I want to connect the data mining tool Weka in my program. Where should the following code will be stored? In the controller or model or somewhere else?

```
require "java"
require "weka"

java_import "java.io.FileReader"
java_import "weka.clusterers.SimpleKMeans"
java_import "weka.core.Instances"

kmeans = SimpleKMeans.new
filereader = FileReader.new ("./labor.arff")
labor_data = Instances.new filereader

#build the cluster and output the k-means data
kmeans.build_clusterer labor_data
puts kmeans.to_string

#examine the particular datapoints
points = labor_data.numInstances
points.times {|instance|
    cluster = kmeans.clusterInstance(labor_data.instance(instance))
    point = labor_data.instance(instance).to_string
    puts "#{point} \t #{cluster}"
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can store it in any part. It depends on what you consider to be model, controller, and view.

Since you are calling "to_string" and printing to the console, there even is a "view" part in your code. So you badly mixed up things!

Maybe you need to reread [Model-View-Controller on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) or your favorite book on design patterns.